# Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'. and :app:lintVitalReportRelease

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, build, build.gradle

I cannot build the app on real device. Here is the error log when i try to build with debug mode.

```
* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
   - with linked exception:
  [org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Premature end of file.]
```

However when i try to build in release mode the error is changing. Here is the release error

```
* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:lintVitalReportRelease'.
> javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
   - with linked exception:
  [org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Premature end of file.]
```

I am searching all over the same questions but nothing helps.
These are the things that i try but failed all.

**1. Change the build-tools version on build.gradle**

```
compileSdkVersion 34
buildToolsVersion "34.0.0"
```

**2. Update Android SDKs and SDK tools to the latest ones.**

**3. Uninstall Android Studio and reinstall it**

**4. flutter doctor -v**
reports no issue

The empty flutter project with these config is also not building.
When i change the app/build.gragle file

```
compileSdkVersion 34
minSdkVersion 21
targetSdkVersion 34
```

**5. Try different gradle version by changing the gradle.wrapper.properties.**
I set distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-all.zip and also update it the gradle file. And also try to upgrade and downgrade the kotlin version.

Could anyone help. I am stuck.

Comment: If you need to see more detail logs. I can paste it with --info or --debug versions of the errors.

Answer (score 0):

Somany solution have to this issue I will provide some solutions,

1.List item Try with change you'r google service versions,

```
 buildscript {
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'
 }
}
```

And now run betllow commands,

Run `flutter clean` and then `flutter pub get`. now try Run to app

2.Wait for Build Tools Update: If changing the Gradle version doesn't work, you might need to wait until the Build Tools V2.0 is out of its alpha stage. Once it's more stable (not in alpha), it could potentially fix the compatibility issue.

3.Contact Crashalytics Team: If neither of the above steps works, reaching out to the Crashalytics team might be helpful. They could assist in resolving the incompatibility issue between your setup and their system.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I found the issue there are 2 android-34 folder i delete both of them and reinstall it again.